# Как очистить предыдущее окно программы Python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, gui

У меня есть программа, в которой есть меню и 2 вкладки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При нажатии на Step 1 открывается первая вкладка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При нажатии на Step 2,  первая вкладка(Step1) должна закрываться, а на её месте должна открываться вкладка Step2. Но у меня в итоге получается это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
win = tk.Tk()
```

Тут создаётся меню:

```
file_menu = Menu(menu_bar, tearoff=0)
file_menu.add_command(label="Step 1", command=step1)
file_menu.add_command(label="Step 2", command=step2)
file_menu.add_separator()
file_menu.add_command(label="Exit", command=_quit)
menu_bar.add_cascade(label="Tasks", menu=file_menu)
```

Две вкладки (Step1 и Step2) создаются в функциях:

```
def step1():
tabControl = ttk.Notebook(win)  # Create Tab Control

    tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)  # Create a tab

    tabControl.add(tab1, text='Завдання 1')  # Add the tab

    lab1 = Label(tab1, text="Моя перша\n\nпрограма!", font=67, width=45, height=3, bg="yellow", fg="blue")
    b1 = Button(tab1, text="Закрити")
    lab1.grid(row=0, column=2, pady=10, ipady=10, ipadx=32, padx=10, sticky="EW")
    b1.grid(row=1, column=2, pady=10, padx=15, sticky="EW")
    b1.bind("<Button-1>")

def step2:
    for id in tabControl.tabs():
        tabControl.forget(id)

    tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)  # Create a tab
    tabControl.add(tab1, text='Завдання 1')  # Add the tab

    tabControl.pack(expand=1, fill="both")  # Pack to make visible

    traffic = ttk.LabelFrame(tab1, text=' Світлофор ')
    traffic.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=8, pady=4)

    remove_control = ttk.LabelFrame(tab1, text=' Пульт ')
    remove_control.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=8, pady=4)
```

Так вот. Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на вторую вкладку, первая закрывалась, а на её месте открывалась вторая?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete widget:

```
widget.destroy()
```